# Unzipping multiple files matching criteria and moving to another location - Python

Tags: python, zip, move, unpack

I'm new here and fairly new to python so any help would be great thanks.

I'm trying to reduce code that I've done and automatically check the next file in the list to be unpacked and moved but I'm finding it difficult as I'm using multiple arguments.

Can anyone find a more simple/automatic way so I don't have to update the code if an extra zip file is required.

```
mainapp.py

        """main program for selecting files from specific folder based on date criteria and extracting chosen file to another location for pickup by the database
"""

def main():
    pass

"""
            Library function imports
"""

import zipfile
import os, sys
import shutil

"""enter code here``
        Clears old data from folder
"""



# List directory
path = "//var//www/html//"
dirs = os.listdir('folder with zips')

"""
            This uses todays date as string, for use to find date in filename
"""

import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat().replace('-','')[:8]

"""
            list that is converted into string for each file
"""

matching = [s for s in dirs if now and ".zip" in s]

import deflator

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    enter code here
```

This is where the issue is, the code works fine and as best as I could get but the problem is these paths are static... can we get this to check until nothing match the criteria

```
deflator.py

def main():
    pass

from mainapp import *

"""counts number of files in dir"""

dircount = len(dirs)

print

"""
        date and file path name join
"""

static_path1 = full_path1 = os.path.join('folder join')


full_path1 = os.path.join(static_path1+matching[0])
full_path2 = os.path.join(static_path1+matching[1])
full_path3 = os.path.join(static_path1+matching[2])
full_path4 = os.path.join(static_path1+matching[3])
full_path5 = os.path.join(static_path1+matching[4])
full_path6 = os.path.join(static_path1+matching[5])

"""
        Defines folder path, compression type, extract path
"""

static_path2 = ('output folder')

deflate_zip = (zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

zip_ref1 = zipfile.ZipFile(full_path1,'r', deflate_zip)
zip_ref1.extractall(static_path2)

zip_ref2 = zipfile.ZipFile(full_path2,'r', deflate_zip)
zip_ref2.extractall(static_path2)

zip_ref3 = zipfile.ZipFile(full_path3,'r', deflate_zip)
zip_ref3.extractall(static_path2)

zip_ref4 = zipfile.ZipFile(full_path4,'r', deflate_zip)
zip_ref4.extractall(static_path2)

zip_ref5 = zipfile.ZipFile(full_path5,'r', deflate_zip)
zip_ref5.extractall(static_path2)

zip_ref6 = zipfile.ZipFile(full_path6,'r', deflate_zip)
zip_ref6.extractall(static_path2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Thank you for your time, any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out but here is my result for anyone who over complicated this in the future.

Can anyone help with extracting the zip with a passsword. Thanks again :)

```
def main():
    pass

import os, zipfile,shutil,datetime

import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat().replace('-','')[:8]

deflate_zip = (zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

import os, glob
zip_ref1 = os.chdir('input folder')
for file in glob.glob('*'+(now)+'.zip'):
   chicken= zipfile.ZipFile(file,'r', deflate_zip,)
   chicken.extractall('output folder')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```